# How to render a html file

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javascript and coding htmls. I am working on a side project and I'm stuck. I have a html file that contains an image(let's call it file1) and I would like to render file1 in another html file called file2. By render I mean display the image contained in file1 in file2. I researched and found stuff like using dataURIs and read a lot about it but it didn't work. I found an encoder online that encoded my file1 to a base 64 and inserted it in my page like this:

```
<img src="data:text/html;base64,PCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWw+CjxodG1sPgo8aGVhZD4KPHRpdGxlPk1hdGhKYXggTGF0ZXggRGlzcGxheSBUZXN0IFBhZ2U8L3RpdGxlPgoKPHNjcmlwdCB0eXBlPSJ0ZXh0L2phdmFzY3JpcHQiIHNyYz0iaHR0cHM6Ly9jMzI4NzQwLnNzbC5jZjEucmFja2Nkbi5jb20vbWF0aGpheC9sYXRlc3QvTWF0aEpheC5qcz9jb25maWc9VGVYLUFNUy1NTUxfU1ZHIj4KPC9zY3JpcHQ+CjwvaGVhZD4KPGJvZHk+ClxbKHRhbih4KSoyeCszKV4yICogXGludCAoeCkgZHhcXQoKPC9ib2R5Pgo8L2h0bWw+Cg==" width="400" height="100" alt="Slide 2">
```

It didn't work and I don't know why. Does any one know any solution for this?

Comment: Do you have a proper server? Sounds like you're looking for "includes".

Comment: That base64 is not an image... it's an HTML webpage. You can't put it in an image tag.

Comment: The resolution I'm looking for is how to render the image contained in file1 in file2. In file2, I'm using the <img> tag. I don't have it hooked to a server yet. I'm just testing it out

Comment: If it's not, how do I include the display the image in the other html file?

Comment: Maybe if you try to explain to us your problem we could come up with a better solution for this? Instead of "I want to display HTML from page1 on page2" you could describe it as "I want to have a slideshow which links to a bigger version of an image".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As sachleen said, your base64 decodes to an HTML page, not an image. And that HTML page does not contain any bitmap images (the `<img>` tag only works with bitmap images like jpg, png and gif; a web page is never an image):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>MathJax Latex Display Test Page</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://c328740.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_SVG">
</script>
</head>
<body>
\[(tan(x)*2x+3)^2 * \int (x) dx\]

</body>
</html>
```

That's JavaScript code generating an SVG (vector) image. Add the same `<script>` tag to the other file, inside `<head>`, and the body text where appropriate. It works on file1, so it should work on file2 as well.

Comment: I added the <script> tag to file2. When I run file1, it displays the svg image correctly but when I run file2, it doesn't display file1's image. the <img> tag only working with bitmaps means it won't be able to display the webpage?

Comment: img is for images like jpg, png and gif. Did you add the text from file1 into file2 too? I mean `\[(tan(x)*2x+3)^2 * \int (x) dx\]`.

Comment: Trying to add \[(tan(x)*2x+3)^2 * \int (x) dx\] might not work because I need the image's src. <img src="src - here" width="400" height="100" alt="Slide 2">, I need to insert the image's src above.

Comment: You can't use img to display that.

Comment: I figured, but I can't just display it on the page. I'm using a gallery( a slider kinda thing) and each slide needs its image. That's why.

Comment: So your options are creating your own image (screenshot of file1), or using a different slider that allows HTML content on the slides.

Comment: yeah, that's what it seems. I will probably try a screenshot. I already found a great script that takes screenshots of pages. The downside is efficiency(time). I might reconsider though. Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it

Answer (score -2):

what't the problem with this (inside file2)

1. `require(file1)`
2. `preg_match($pattern, $file1, $result)`
3. `<img src="$result" />`

Comment: There's nothing in the question to suggest PHP is a viable solution